# Checking whether a function is monotonic or not

Tags: c++, math

I have a function and I want to check whether it is monotonic or not within a particular domain. I can substitute all the points in the domain and check for monotonicity of the function but that is a rather naive approach. Is there any other way by which I can check whether a function is monotonic or not within a domain in C++?

Comment: @user3386109 The function is use defined, so it can be anything

Comment: this is a difficult problem to solve numerically. For example, would `x == 4.52342788 ? x : 0` be a valid function to check ? It's monotonically increasing for most of the real axis except at one point and it's very unlikely that you'll find this point. You should specify which assumptions can be made about the functions to be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can do something like that

```
enum monotonic_e {
    MONOTONIC_INCREASE, /* function is monotonically increasing */
    MONOTONIC_DECREASE, /* function is monotonically decreasing */
    MONOTONIC_CONSTANS, /* function is constant */
    MONOTONIC_NOT       /* function is not monotonic */   
};
double sign(double x) {
    return x < 0 ? -1. : (x > 0 ? 1. : 0.);
}
monotonic_e monotonic(const function< double(double) >& f,
                      double a, double b, double eps) {
    double x = a, y1 = f(x), y2 = f(x + eps);
    double d = y2 - y1;
    double s = sign(d);
    while( x < b ) {
        x += eps;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = f(x + eps);
        d = y2 - y1;
        if( s == 0. ) {
            s = sign(d);
        }
        if( s * d < 0 ) {
            return MONOTONIC_NOT;
        }
    }
    return s > 0 ? MONOTONIC_INCREASE :
          (s < 0 ? MONOTONIC_DECREASE :
                   MONOTONIC_CONSTANS);
}
```

If you have to check a huge range of values you can parallelize this by partitioning whole range to smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample implementation for the special case of a domain consisting of a finite number of points (you can't really check arbitrary mathematical functions and their ranges with C++ -- not enough memory/CPU power to store/check ranges that are uncountably infinite):

```
std::function<double(double)> myFunction; //Set this to your function

std::vector<double> domain;  //Fill this in with your domain of interest

double previous_value = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();

auto first_non_mono_value = 
    std::find_if(domain.begin(), domain.end(),
        [&myFunction](double this_input)
        {
            double this_output = myFunction(this_input);
            if(previous_value > this_output)
                return true; //Violation of monotonic assumption

            previous_value = this_output;
            return false;  //Still may be monitonic (need to check next point)
        });

if(first_non_mono_value == domain.end())
{
    cout << "MONOTONIC" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Not monotonic" << endl;
}
```

WARNING: I did not compile this -- so it may have bugs, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question as I am not able to understand this implementation..does the function find_if check for monotonicity on each and every value of the sub-domain. If not then how should I go about it?

Comment: It does check them sequentially, until it gets to a point where the monotonicity is false, then it kicks out (because there is no reason to check the rest of them).  This implementation uses lambda functions which requires a compiler compliant with C++11

Comment: Ok. But my problem is I can not afford to check for monotonicity at each and every point as the amount of data that I have runs into Tera Bytes.

Comment: If you don't have any a priori knowledge of your function you will need to check every value